# Laptop connects to wireless network but gets invalid ip?

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking

My laptop's wireless randomly stopped working.
I'm in a hostel in Sydney, everyone in the house is connecting just fine, however my laptop is connecting to the wireless network but getting an "Invalid IP" and the icon has that yellow exclamation mark.

I went to a McDonalds this morning to try the wifi there and it connected just fine.
I also tried restarting the router, same thing.

Any ideas on what might be wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Check your credentials and wireless setup.  Make sure you have the correct passphrases/key and the correct encryption e.g. WPA or WPA2 or whatever it's using.  It must match the router.

I'm fairly sure it's just connecting at the wireless level but not authenticating so therefore it's not able to communicate with the DHCP server but just self assigning an address.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your security key is correct - Remember it is case sensitive.

Sometimes when you get the case wrong, it can "connect" (or more accurately, report connected) but errors like this occur.

Next, check the security method - AES, TKIP, then make sure you have the right mode - WPA, WPA2 etc.

If you are sure it is correct, try dropping the security off temporarily and see if you can connect.

If you still can't connect, check MAC filtering on the router.

If you can connect when open, but not when secured, and you are sure the settings are correct, try updating your driver.